# Powershell to update dates

Tags: powershell

I have an array with months. Now I would like to update a field with the date but I don't want to create 12 different if statement for this. What are my other option? (The code i wrote works but trying to minimize the line numbers)

For example,

```
if(month=1)
{ $item["RequestDate"] = "1/31/2016"}
if(month=2)
{...}
if(month=3)
{...}
```

Actual code

```
$MonthArray = @("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6")

for($i=0; $i -lt $MonthArray.length; $i++)
{
   if($i="1")
   {
     $item["RequestedDate"] = "01/31/2016"
   }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is this

```
$MonthArray = @("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6")
$year = '2016'

foreach ($month in $MonthArray) {

$start_date = Get-Date -Format 'MM/dd/yyyy' -Day  ([datetime]::DaysInMonth($year, $month)) -Month $month -Year $year
$start_date
}
```

This code assumes date you're interested is last day of month and this year. In case you need this for more months this can be still extended within $MonthArray variable, but for more years this will need additional loop.

Comment: WOW. Perfect. Thank you Martin. Never thought it would be this simple.

Answer (score 2):

You can insert the month using string format, but be aware that 31. feb + a few more of these dates doesn't exist.

```
$MonthArray = @(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

for($i=0; $i -lt $MonthArray.length; $i++)
{
    #$item["RequestedDate"] = "{0:00}/31/2016" -f $MonthArray[$i]
    "{0:00}/31/2016" -f $MonthArray[$i]
}
```

Output:

```
01/31/2016
02/31/2016
03/31/2016
04/31/2016
05/31/2016
06/31/2016
```

Or using datetime-objects. This will fail with invalid dates, so I used 16. each month:

```
$MonthArray = @(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

for($i=0; $i -lt $MonthArray.length; $i++)
{
    #$date = [datetime]"$($MonthArray[$i])/16/2016"
    $date = New-Object datetime -ArgumentList 2016, ($MonthArray[$i]), 16
    $date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your post. I just used Martin's post as it was shorter. Thanks again for pitching in.

Comment: No problem. You could one-line this as well but readability > short code. :-)